# PHP- curl isn't working?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use an SMS Gateway API with PHP. My code is:

```
<?php
 // API integration
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     //Variables to POST
     $username = "user";
     $password = "pass";
     $msisdn = $_POST['phone'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];

     //Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://bulksms.vsms.net:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
              array('username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'msisdn' => $msisdn)
              );

     //Execute CURL command and return into variable $result

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     echo "$result";
 }
?>
 <form name='sms' action='' method='post'>
 Phone number (eg.: 919999999999, separated by commas) <br/><input type='text' name='phone' value=''/>
 Message: <br/><input type='textarea' name='message' value=''/> 
 <br/>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send SMS'>
 </form>
```

This isn't working, neither it is echoing the `$result`. Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` give you?

Comment: check if any error in cURL, do: if(curl_errno($ch)) { echo curl_error($ch); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://www.bulksms.com/int/docs/eapi/submission/faq/) states the following on using port 5567:

> You can fall back to port 80 if you have firewall-related problems connecting to us (but we recommend that you rather take the time to allow outgoing access to ports 5567 and 7512 via your firewall). To do so, simply remove :5567 (or similar) from the URL.

Therefore, you could try the fallback port (80).

Comment: wooh! i was actually doing that and then you commented :p and that solved :)

Comment: Changing the port to 80

Comment: I've edited your answer and upvoted it, because the problem is documented ... the question is not so useful, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to check out your problem first and then further step forward

```
$error=curl_error($ch);    //print_r($error); 
$header=curl_getinfo( $ch ); //print_r($header);
$result = curl_exec($ch);  //print_r($result);
```

Comment: try to enable by removing ; from extension=php_curl.dll on your php.ini file

Comment: try to post your data as @Sudhir suggested

Answer (score 0):

your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is invalid, do:

```
.....
$postData = array('username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'message' => $message,
    'msisdn' => $msisdn
);

//create post body  
$post_body = '';
foreach( $postData as $key => $value ) {
    $post_body .= urlencode( $key ).'='.urlencode( $value ).'&';
}
$post_body = rtrim( $post_body,'&' );
```

and change following line:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,...);
...
```

to

```
..
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);
...
echo $result;
```

Comment: as it seems to be working fine for me.. except that the response is 'Invalid credentials'

Comment: I've solved that. but still its not printing $result

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the php_curl.dll in your php.ini file, 
if it has a ; remove it try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode POST query into string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'msisdn' => $msisdn), '', '&');

              );
```

Comment: I don't think that would make any difference.